# CAST and CONVERT both failing when attempting to convert string to date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, type-conversion

I'm dealing with a table containing records from questionnaires administered to people after completing an activity. There are several questions on the questionnaire, so each person has multiple records with the same collection date, like so.

```
PersonID   Question            Result         CollectedDate
-------------------------------------------------------------
1001       First activity?     Yes            10/23/2022
1001       Activity date       10/20/2022     10/23/2022
1001       Activity type       Painting       10/23/2022
1002       First activity?     No             10/24/2022
1002       Activity date       10/23/2022     10/24/2022
1002       Activity type       Writing        10/24/2022
```

Since my end goal is to compare the activity date with the questionnaire collection date and see how much time elapsed between them, I've altered my query a bit so I'm focusing only on each person's question regarding the activity date. It's a super simple query:

```
SELECT
    PersonID,
    Question,
    Result,
    CollectedDate

FROM Questionnaire
WHERE Question LIKE '%date%'


PersonID   Question            Result         CollectedDate
-------------------------------------------------------------
1001       Activity date       10/20/2022     10/23/2022
1002       Activity date       10/23/2022     10/24/2022
```

My main issue is that the `Result` field is `varchar(50)` in order to accommodate text answers, so any dates seen there are actually from free text fields in the front-end interface. I've tried using both `CAST()` and `CONVERT()` to turn it into an actual date format so the difference between the dates can be calculated. I've seen both of the following errors depending on which function I'm using or which date/time style I'm attempting to apply:

`Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string`

`The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value`

I've tried:

```
SELECT
    PersonID,
    Question,
    CAST(Result as date),
    CollectedDate

FROM Questionnaire
WHERE Question LIKE '%date%'
```

and...

```
SELECT
    PersonID,
    Question,
    CONVERT(DATETIME,Result,101) as Result,
    CollectedDate

FROM Questionnaire
WHERE Question LIKE '%date%'
```

...and have tried several different styles. Does anyone have any further suggestions? Is the date itself likely the problem, or is if the fact that the `Result` field contains a bunch of other stuff too, even though it's currently omitted from the query results?

**UPDATE:** There are some kind of wonky date formats in this `Result` field even when I have the other question types filtered out (I hate free text). For example, there are some formatted like `05/01/2022` and others like `5/1/2022`. Some others have something like `5/19/2022 - 5/20/2022`, like maybe the person couldn't remember the exact date of their activity. What's the best way to deal with all of this?

Comment: try using "try_convert" instead of "convert".

Comment: The best way is to not let users enter dates as text. What date is `05/01/2022`? Is it the first of may, or the 5th of January? How can you possibly know? Without any detail about how you collect these data, it's hard to say how this could be best accomplished

Comment: @Kostya that gives me the error `TRY_CONVERT is not a recognized built-in function name.` Is that a newer function? I'm using an older version of SQL Server so I might not be able to use certain functions...

Comment: @HoneyBadger oh I would LOVE to not allow anybody to use free text. Luckily we're upgrading to a new front-end system soon-ish and the plan is to force as much as we can to be structured data.

Comment: @EJF, `TRY_CONVERT` was introduced in sql server 2012, so I wouldn't call it a "new" function. Sounds like you're using an unsupported version of sql server, all the more reason to upgrade

Comment: @HoneyBadger yeah, I just checked and I'm only using 2008. The new front-end system will also include an upgrade of SQL Server, but for now I'm stuck with this. Any other suggestions for how to deal with my issue, or am I out of options with this older version?

Comment: You have bad data (which is what happens when you let people enter free text). You can find it this way: `SELECT * FROM dbo.Questionnaire WHERE ISDATE(Result) = 0;` But keep in mind some things will return `ISDATE()=1` even if they aren't _recognizable_ dates (`1/2/3`) or if they are transposed (`12/05/2022` may have been entered even if `05/12/2022` is what was intended).

Comment: @EJF You need to clean your data, so the dates are in the format you expect them to be. But you still have to make assumptions which may not be correct. There may be all kinds of weird dates in there, typos and all. There is no sure way to correct it to what the user meant at the time

Comment: 2008 has been *completely* unsupported for well over 3 years at this stage, @EJF . If you're using such an old, outdated, and unsupported version you should really be letting the users know that in the question.

Comment: this might work - "IIF(ISDATE(dates)= 1, cast(Result  as date) , null) "

Comment: Store dates as `DATE`, not `VARCHAR`, and sleep well at night. This is not JSON.

Comment: @Kostya `IIF` won't work in SQL Server 2008. But I don't know if ignoring malformed data is better than identifying it, fixing it, and getting rid of the error that way...

Comment: Look everyone, I would love to have a new version of SQL Server, and I would love to not have to deal with free text. In this particular case, the date in the `Result` field is stored as `varchar` because there are a ton of other text-based answers for other questions on the questionnaire. I did not build this database, I did not design the crappy front-end system. But it's what I have to work with.

Comment: Your table design is entirely wrong. You should not be storing dates in `Result`. You should instead be storing something like `Complete`, and have a separate DATE column to store the completion date. When you design your table to mix data types in the same column, you end up jumping through hoops to do simple tasks like you're doing now.

Comment: @KenWhite I didn't design this table or this database and I have no control over how the front-end system stores its data, so...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get past the error by making sure you reject any value that can't be converted to a date. Largely, that is this:

```
Result = CASE 
  WHEN ISDATE(Result) = 1 THEN CONVERT(date, Result, 101) END
```

You'd think it would be enough to say `WHERE Question = 'Activity Date' AND ISDATE(Result) = 1`, but:

1. Someone still might have entered bad data on that row.
2. SQL Server might try to perform the `CONVERT()` operation *before* the filter.

You can identify the ones that have bad data using:

```
WHERE Question = 'Activity Date' AND ISDATE(Result) = 0
```

But until you've fixed the structure and stored dates in an independent column, fixing that data just means it's a matter of time before it happens again.

You might consider, in the meantime, just displaying what the user entered as a string, instead of trying to force it to be converted to a date. Especially since 101 might be a bad guess - what if the user is from the UK or Canada? They may have entered 05/12 and meant December 5th, not May 12th.